# Trying to create an Azure AD application with Terraform using azured provider. Creating that Using a service principal in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory, azure-rm

I have configured a service principal to create resources using terraform and exported all the variables as given [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret). Also added the permission Application.readwrite.all for this Service principal.

Trying to create a AzureAd Application and a client secret for the Application but receiving an error that says insufficient permissions to create.

not sure what permissions do we require. can anyone help with what need to be added to the terraform's service principal so that it can create applications in Azure AD.

This is the error [image]

These are the API Permissions.
[image]

if this is added at the enterprise application will it be sufficient to perform those action , because even after this , i still see not granted at the app registration. [image]

App registration screenshot
[image]

Comment: Could you include how you added `Application.readwrite.all` to the service principal and confirm whether you granted **admin consent** to permission or not?

Comment: i have added it via the portal itself and yes , i haven;t granted admin consent in the app registration as well as in the enterprise application. 

is it a requirement that admin consent has to be made to make it work ?

Comment: Could you include the `API permissions` screenshot by editing your question? You need to grant **admin consent** for the added permission to resolve the error.

Comment: Updated the question with API Permissions, But can this consent be provided at the enterprise application level as well .

Comment: Granting admin consent in [API permissions](https://i.imgur.com/DkTiCZw.png) will automatically add consent to service principal in [Enterprise application](https://i.imgur.com/93HvWkC.png) level too.

Comment: Okay Thanks, So to continue forward i need to get admin consent either at app registration or enterprise application right

Comment: i think i do not have that permissions to grant that consent for that application in my tenant. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254725/discussion-between-sridevi-and-chaitanyasai).

Answer (score 0):

> The error usually occurs if the service principal does not have
> required **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation.

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **`API permissions`** as below:

[image]

When I ran below terraform code to read display name of specific application, I too got **same error**:

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
    client_id     = "appID"
    client_secret = "secret"
    tenant_id     = "tenantID"
}

data "azuread_application" "example" {
      object_id = "appObjID"
}

output "azure_ad_display_name" {
      value = data.azuread_application.example.display_name
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to grant **admin consent** to the added API permission named *Application.ReadWrite.All*:

[image]

When I ran the same code again after granting consent, I got **display name** in response:

[image]

To create Azure AD application, I ran below terraform code:

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {
    client_id     = "appID"
    client_secret = "secret"
    tenant_id     = "tenantID"
}

# Create an application
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
   display_name = "SriTFapp"
}

# Create a service principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
   application_id = azuread_application.example.application_id
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where application named `SriTFapp` created successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will may be try this in my own tenant. Seems admin consent is the problem, Can you also let me know if you were able to create secret for azuread_application that you have created.

Comment: Yes you can create client secret too. Check this thread for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76804627/how-to-create-azure-app-registration-and-client-secret-using-terraform)