# How to create azure app registration and client secret using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create an Terraform code for Azure app registration and client secret (A service principal with Read access to the subscription)

Basically, I am trying to Integrate Azuresafe with Terraform and trying to identify how to configure step by step.https://docs.safe.security/docs/azure. If there is already any terrafrom code out there to review etc.. will be helpful or for this **I would like to understand how to create a app registration and clien secret.**

```
# Create new app registration
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = var.azuread_app_display_name
}

# Create a service principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "app" {
  application_id = azuread_application.app.application_id
}

# Create Service Principal password
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "app" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.app.object_id
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to create Azure app registration, Service principal & client secret using Terraform and I was successfully able to provision them

Here as per the requirement, we need need to provision Azure App registration & its secret, Service principal in read-only access. For this, we need contributor-level access to our active subscription.

my terraform code

**main.tf**

```
resource  "azuread_application"  "app" {

display_name  =  "Azuresafe Application VK"

}

 
resource  "azuread_service_principal"  "app" {

application_id  =  azuread_application.app.application_id

}

 
resource  "azuread_application_password"  "example" {

application_object_id  =  azuread_application.app.object_id

}

   
# Output the Service Principal and password

output  "app" {

value  =  azuread_application.app.id

sensitive  =  true

}


output  "app_password" {

value  =  azuread_application_password.example.value

sensitive  =  true

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

now execute the `terrafrom_output` command to check the app and app_secret

**terraform_output**

[image]

[image]

**Portal Output:**

```
App Registration
```

[image]

```
App registration password
```

[image]

Comment: I am kind of running into this error Error: Invalid provider configuration

Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread" requires explicit
configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the
provider's required arguments as described in the provider documentation.


Error: unable to build authorizer for Resource Manager API: could not configure AzureCli Authorizer: could not parse Azure CLI version: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": 

  with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread"],
  on <empty> line 0:
  (source code not available)

Comment: Check with client_id, client_secret, and tenant_id arguments These arguments are used to authenticate with the Azure Active Directory service.
If the provided info is correct check with az cli version by executing the commands
az --version
&
az upgrade

Once you done upgrading try running the terraform again

Comment: ok, I was able to fix that! Thank u! so this part is done

Comment: Now, any idea on how to give read access to this created service principal for the subscription?

Comment: resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "read_access" {
  scope = azuread_service_principal.app.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id = azuread_service_principal.app.id
}
For this you need 
Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/providers/read access in your subscription

Comment: I needed for multiple subscription, but failing, 
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "read_access_exauto" {
  provider             = azurerm.exam1-prod
  scope                = data.azurerm_read_access.exauto.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader" 
  principal_id         = azuread_appregistration.principal.id
}


resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "read_access_pop" {
  provider             = azurerm.exam2-prod
  scope                = azuread_application.app.scope 
  role_definition_name = "Reader" 
  principal_id         = azuread_appregistration.principal.id 
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809424/how-to-give-read-access-to-the-app-registration-for-multiple-subscriptions-in-az

you can use this for your reference requirement.