# How to give read access to the app registration for multiple subscriptions in azure via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following terraform code to create a app registration and client secret, And I am looking for some help **to assign a reader role for this app registration for multiple subscriptions**.below code is failing with syntax error? can someone help on this on what am I missing?

```
    # Create new app registration
resource "azuread_application" "appregistration" {
  display_name = var.appregistration_display_name
}

# Create client secret
resource "azuread_application_password" "app" {
  display_name          = var.clientsecret_display_name
  application_object_id = azuread_application.app.id
}

# Role assignment for app registration
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "read_access_exauto" {
  provider             = azurerm.exam1-prod
  scope                = data.azurerm_read_access.exauto.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader" 
  principal_id         = azuread_appregistration.principal.id
}

# Role assignment for app registration
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "read_access_pop" {
  provider             = azurerm.exam2-prod
  scope                = azuread_application.app.scope 
  role_definition_name = "Reader" 
  principal_id         = azuread_appregistration.principal.id 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.64.0"
    }
  }
}

# Defined providers
provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "exam1-prod"
  subscription_id = "9b91fe1a-76c8-4b75-9d27-f214d69c2872"
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "exam2-prod"
  subscription_id = "a4cbac6c-7051-4914-b3b8-adbf01218554"
  features {}
}

# Get data from subscription
data "azurerm_subscription" "exam1-prod" {
    provider               = azurerm.exam1-prod
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "exam2-prod" {
    provider               = azurerm.exam2-prod
}

# Create App Registration
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = var.appregistration_display_name
}

# Create a service principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "sp" {
  application_id = azuread_application.app.application_id
}

# Reader Role in subscription 1 
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "read_access_exauto" {
provider               = azurerm.exam1-prod
  scope                  = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.exam1-prod.subscription_id}"
  role_definition_name   = "Reader"
  principal_id           = azuread_service_principal.sp.object_id
}

# Reader Role in subscription 2 
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "read_access_pop" {
  provider               = azurerm.exam2-prod
  scope                  = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.exam2-prod.subscription_id}"
  role_definition_name   = "Reader"
  principal_id           = azuread_service_principal.sp.object_id
}
```

Let me know if it works by accepting the answer.

### NOTE: **The code has been updated**

Comment: Running into this error, GetProvider : Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'azurerm'

Comment: Hi, @saravanaraj I updated the code and tested it again. This version should work in your case. Let me know if it works.